# Se usa una conexión a base de datos por cada PreparedStatement que ejecuta cada hilo?

Tags: java, mysql, hilos, jdbc

La pregunta es simple, uso hilos de ejecución y a cada hilo le paso la misma conexión a base de datos (Solo abro una conexión) lo que no se es, por ser una sola conexión, ¿se ejecutan los PreparedStatement paralelamente (por cada hilo simultáneamente) o se ejecuta uno a la vez haciendo un cuello de botella (se espera a que termine uno para ejecutar otro)?

Adjunto fragmento de codigo, aunque en realidad no es muy necesario.

**NOTA: los PreparedStatement son independientes para cada hilo**

```
    public int actualizaMetadata(PreparedStatement ps, DatosMetadata datosMetadata) throws Exception, SQLException {
    int resultado;
    int registrados = 0;
    try {
        ps.setBigDecimal(1, datosMetadata.getSubtotal());
        ps.setBigDecimal(2, datosMetadata.getTotal_retenidos());
        ps.setBigDecimal(3, datosMetadata.getTotal_trasladados());
        ps.setBigDecimal(4, datosMetadata.getDescuento());
        ps.setString(5, datosMetadata.getMetodoPago());
        ps.setString(6, datosMetadata.getSerie());
        ps.setString(7, datosMetadata.getFolio());
        ps.setString(8, datosMetadata.getUsoCFDI());
        ps.setString(9, datosMetadata.getMoneda());
        ps.setString(10, datosMetadata.getUuid());
        resultado = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (resultado <= 0) {
            throw new Exception("El UUID: " + datosMetadata.getUuid() + " No esta registrado en la tabla de Metadatos. ");
        }
        if (resultado > 0) {
            registrados++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        ps.clearParameters();
    }

    return registrados;
}
```